# jquery fancybox close errors

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Have the following in an fancybox ajax call

```
               $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'sendmesse.php',
                    data: $("#messform").serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data == "true") {
                            $("#messform").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                                $(this).before("<strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong>");
                                setTimeout($.fancybox.close(), 1000);
                                // $('.fancybox').close();
                                // $.fancybox.close();

                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

all works fine appart from the closing, tried various variations without sucess.
The timeout above gives me 
    `Error: useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)`

so i tried both 
`setTimeout('$.fancybox.close()', 1000);`
and
`setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);`
to which i get the following error `TypeError: $ is undefined`

...help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as shown below:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $.fancybox.close();}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` expects either a function reference or a string to evaluate. In your case try calling `setTimeout` like:

```
setTimeout(function() { $.fancybox.close(); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creation a simple function called "closeMyFancyBox" such as

```
function closeMyFancyBox() {
$.fancybox.close();
}
```

Then call that function as `setTimeout('closeMyFancyBox', 1000);`